# How to mount host directory into docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to mount /var/www/html directory into docker container using VOLUME command in dockerfile.
But we can provide only guest volume location (or target location) using VOLUME command. How can I provide the host location (or source location) inside my dockerfile.

Comment: You can't specify that a certain host directory should be mounted to the container in the Dockerfile. You need to do that when you run the image.

Comment: If that directory contains your application, you can also `COPY` it into the image instead of using a volume.  That will make the image self-contained and it will be easier to integration-test and deploy; but it will not be a live-reloading development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify that a certain host directory should be mounted to the container in the Dockerfile. You need specify that in docker-compose.yaml like example given below.

```
volumes:

  # Just specify a path and let the Engine create a volume

    - /var/lib/mysql

  # Specify an absolute path mapping

    - /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql

  # Path on the host, relative to the Compose file

    - ./cache:/tmp/cache

  # User-relative path

    - ~/configs:/etc/configs/:ro

  # Named volume

    - datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: That's taken from the docker-compose documentation. Docker-compose specifies how images should be run. Dockerfiles (which was what you asked about) specify how the images should be built.

Comment: That's not possible to provide bridged mount in dockerfile.